# Why does Bootstrap cause so many console warnings?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Seriously, why are there so many warnings and how can I keep these from crowding my logs?

[image: Bootstrap Errors]

Comment: In the drop down in your console tab, untick *show CSS errors*.

Comment: @Prabhakaran Thanks! I wasn't able to find that before posting this. I'll close this. Sounds like there's no way to clear the warnings.